# Keep related text next to floated image

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I'm working on a responsive webpage that has photos of people's faces as floated IMGs next to some descriptive text about each person.

[image: what it's meant to look like]

This works very well at smaller page widths, but when the page gets wide, the text associated with the next person starts next to the previous person's image.

[image: not so good]

I need a way to force text appear no higher than the top of the particular image.

I've set up a JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/clayRav/k36nhs1e/).

```css
img {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x300">
<h1>First person's name</h1>
<p>A few paras of text.</p>
<img src="https://placehold.it/300x300">
<h1>Second person's name</h1>
<p>A few paras of text.</p>
```

Note: the `clear: both` is there to make sure the second image doesn't float to the right of the first image.

EDIT: Ideally I would do this without using any special markup, such as DIVs and inline style. The reason for this is that this content is being entered into our CMS by non-technical staff using the TinyMCE editor. Ideally these people wouldn't need to know any HTML. So I would really prefer a CSS-only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *clear* the `float` after the `p` element using:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

See demo below:

```css
#container img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  <h1>
    First person's name
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in.
    Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida
    rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
  </p>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  <h1>
    Second person's name
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in.
    Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida
    rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
  </p>
</div>
```

If markup can't be changed, you can use a *pseudo* element to `p`:

```
p:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

See demo below:

```css
#container img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}
p:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  <h1>
    First person's name
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in.
    Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida
    rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
  </p>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  <h1>
    Second person's name
  </h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in.
    Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida
    rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for that! Ideally I would want to solve this problem without using extra HTML, ie just in the CSS relating to img, h1 and p tags. That way non-technical staff can add the content. See my edited question.

Comment: @clayRay check out the edited answer that do not change the markup

Comment: Thanks @kukkuz that does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Bootstrap column structure

```css
#container img {
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div id="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <h1>First person's name</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in. Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/360x360">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6">
      <h1>Second person's name</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque id ex ut nunc pharetra congue. Morbi ut lectus vulputate nunc congue convallis. Nunc ultricies quam ac dolor tincidunt feugiat. Integer condimentum metus leo, a interdum felis molestie in. Ut non diam non ligula aliquam iaculis vestibulum quis urna. Maecenas efficitur purus et elementum auctor. Praesent condimentum id sapien vitae tempor. Ut ultrices accumsan lectus, quis ullamcorper velit auctor at. Suspendisse bibendum, odio gravida rhoncus pretium, enim elit porta massa, quis sagittis dolor sapien vel nulla. Nullam et enim ac tellus aliquam pulvinar. Proin et bibendum dui.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I may need to take this approach, but ideally the content would just be IMG, P and heading tags, so that non-technical staff can enter it. I was hoping for a CSS-only solution. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **divs** and clear **elements pseudo selector before and after**
[Demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/k36nhs1e/6/)

```
.top-content:after, .top-content:before {
   display: block;
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I may need to take such an approach, but ideally the content would just be IMG, P and heading tags, so that non-technical staff can enter it. I was hoping for a CSS-only solution. See my edited answer.