# back to line when using float left

Tags: html, css

I should align the fixed width divs.

I have a container with a fixed width

I have dynamic divs inside but they also have a fixed width.

I would like to put 4 divs per line.

So I used CSS's `float` rule

My actual problem is that when the last div (card) on the line has a short height the next card gets under it.

What I'm expecting is the next div get back to a complete line.

```css
.card {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
.container {
  width: 900px;
}
.shortcard {
  height:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card shortcard">

</div>
<div class="card">
It should be in next line
</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
</div>
```

When the height is longer, the element is getting to another line

```css
.card {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
.container {
  width: 900px;
}
.shortcard {
  height:50px
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
<div class="card ">

</div>
<div class="card">
I'm ok here
</div>
<div class="card">

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something [like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/gpoyve28/)

Comment: when using floats, you should clear them (add `clear: left` to the div with text *I'm ok here*)... some resources and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39684091, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45728347, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39311775

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you are trying to achieve is that, you don't want the long div to come under the short div. So for that, you have to use `inline-block` with `float: left` like

```
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block; /* to line up the divs in a single line */
  float:left; /* to make them stick to the top */
}
```

```css
.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.shortcard {
  height: 50px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="card">

  </div>
  <div class="card">

  </div>
  <div class="card">

  </div>
  <div class="card shortcard">

  </div>
  <div class="card containerdivNewLine">
    beside short div but not under it
  </div>
  <div class="card">

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I try to fix this in your code, so that you understand better!

so basic changes are css, create a new class `.container` and use `display: flex` properties.

have a look:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    I'm ok here
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</div>

.card {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container
{
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```css
.card {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.container
{
  display: flex;
  width: 900px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    I'm ok here
    </div>
    <div class="card">
    </div>
</div>
```

run the code, and let me know if you want a design like this or not?